# How to run an executable file with c language?

Tags: c, system

I was trying to execute this program using C language compiler 3.0 every thing is going alright but when i run this program it never open firefox and when i run this program`s executable file it shows compatibility issue errors :( please help me

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: which Operating system ?

Comment: @Omkant - clearly windows from the path.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx is a Win32 API entry for that

Comment: @Mike No proof: `ls -l` shows  `-rw-r--r-- 1 dafis users    17 24. Nov 16:24 C:\Program Files(x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the execve function : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyw61wtd(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Replace "\\" with "/"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    system("C:/Program file(x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe");
    return 0;
}
```