# How to run other executable file using c program

Tags: c, windows

I have an executable file at location   **D:/a.exe**. I changes its extension to **a.txt**. Now I would like to execute it using c program.
i am following c code.

```
#include<windows.h>

system("start D:/a.txt");
// or
system("D:/a.txt");
```

The program doesn't execute it but open it into Notepad. How do I execute **a.txt** which is in reality is an executable file?

Comment: Try `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Watch Out This Question You Will Find Solution...

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541956/how-to-run-an-executable-file-with-c-language

Comment: Use `CreateProcessW` on Windows and the `exec` family of functions on Unix.

Comment: This is not a C question, but one about DOS/Windows. I added tags.

Comment: @meaning-matters: the OP is very unlikely to be using DOS; it has neither the `start` command nor notepad.  I've removed the DOS tag.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the OS version and settings. `system` uses the command interpreter that's set in the `COMSPEC` environment variable. The default is cmd, which always tries `CreateProcess` before falling back on `ShellExecuteEx`, so it should work; it does for me in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

First you rename it then you launch it. You cannot launch a txt extension as an executable file.

```
#include<windows.h>

char oldname[] = "D:/a.txt";
char newname[] = "D:/a.exe";

ret = rename(oldname, newname);

if(ret == 0) 
{
    system("start D:/a.exe");
}
```